# Need access Kendo Grid data row wise

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have used Kendo Grid in my project, i need access values in each row, row wise. And need to compare the values between two columns.

For example:-

```
 Student ID   Student Name  Student Physics Student Chemistry

 1          xxx            22                  44
 2          yyy            33                  11
```

The marks between two columns is required to be compared, and have to highlight the cell which contain less value.

Any row wise data iteration example would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Dipak

Answer (score 0):

This is how you access the data row wise.

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        data:[
                {
                 "Id":1,
                 "Name":"xxx",
                  "Physics":22,
                  "Chemistry":44
                },{
                "Id":2,
                "Name":"yyy",
                "Physics":33,
                "Chemistry":11
               }
              ]
    },
     pageable: true,
        height: 550,
        columns: [
            { field: "Id", title: "Id"  },
            { field: "Name", title: "Name"  },
            { field: "Physics", title: "Physics"},
            { field: "Chemistry", title: "Chemistry"},
            ]
 });

var studentsGrid= $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");       
var data = studentsGrid.dataSource.data();
for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
     // access data row wise
    console.log(data[i].Chemistry);
    console.log(data[i].Physics);
}
```

```html
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
   </body>
```